# What does requestCode and resultCode in onActivityResult refer to?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button, onactivityresult

Good day guys. I'm new to android and now using **startActivityForResult** in my program. In my app, I have two button and two textView. The two `button` used to open the dialog. How can I check which button was pressed onActivityResult so that the TextView can be setText accordingly to the button?

```
  int a1 = 1;
  int a2 = 2;

   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialogRadio(a1);

            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialogRadio(a2);

            }
        });

 public void AlertDialogRadio(final int k) {  //parameter k is never used
            final CharSequence[] ClaimsModel = {"Project", "Petrol", "Car Maintenance"
                    , "Medical", "Other"};

            AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alt_bld.setTitle("Select a Claims");
            alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(ClaimsModel, -1, new DialogInterface
                    .OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (item == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Project1.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    } else if (item == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Petrol.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    } else if (item == 2) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CarMainten.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                    } else if (item == 3) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Medical.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
                    } else if (item == 4) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Other.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 4);
                    }

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
            alert.show();
        }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == 1) { // if button1 was clicked
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    String result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    c.setText("            " + b + "------" + "RM " + result);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not completed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    String result1 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b1 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    c.setText("            " + b1 + "------" + "RM " + result1);
                    break;


                case 2:
                    String result2 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b2 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    c.setText("            " + b2 + "------" + "RM " + result2);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    String result3 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b3 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    c.setText("            " + b3 + "------" + "RM " + result3);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    String result4 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b4 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    c.setText("            " + b4 + "------" + "RM " + result4);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == 2) { // if button2 was clicked
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    String result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    d.setText("            " + b + "------" + "RM " + result);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    String result1 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b1 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    d.setText("            " + b1 + "------" + "RM " + result1);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    String result2 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b2 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    d.setText("            " + b2 + "------" + "RM " + result2);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    String result3 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b3 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    d.setText("            " + b3 + "------" + "RM " + result3);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    String result4 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b4 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    d.setText("            " + b4 + "------" + "RM " + result4);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So my program should work like this:
If button1 was clicked....c.setText();
If button2 was clicked....d.setText();

But the program now is **nothing display on the TextView**. Did the error came from  `if (resultCode == 1)` and `else if (resultCode == 2)` ?? Thanks a lot

Assume the use select `Project1.class`

**Project1.class**

```
public class Project1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String text;
    private static String a;
    private static EditText txt;
    private int g;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project);
       txt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText36);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                a="Project";
                text = txt.getText().toString();
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                returnIntent.putExtra("a",a);
              //  returnIntent.putExtra("k",getIntent().getExtras().getString("k"));
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone can help ? Thanks

Comment: `requestCode` is for who, `resultCode` is for result, do u use `setResult' in `OtherActivity`?

Comment: Ya,I have used setResult in the 5 activities.

Comment: replace `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` to `getActivity`;

Comment: cannot resolve getActivity.

Comment: How can I pass the parameter k to new Intent and then return back the parameter k to onActivityResult to check which button was clicked?

Comment: Can u paste ur OtherActivity code?

Comment: Does `onActivityResult` invoked?

Comment: i tested it it's ok!     my result: 10-28 19:15:20.251 21866-21866/ I/TestFragment: requestCode:200,resultCode:-1,data:testString5

Comment: resultCode == -1(Activity.RESULT_OK) will be ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

request_code is the calling function identity, from where it is requested, result_code is the called function identifier, also it specifies status of the called message as Intent.ACTIVITY_OK and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but tt would be better if you help to solve my problem as well :)

Comment: Please use ACTIVITY_OK first instead of 1, and try removing finish() after setResult(), it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the literal code here.

```
if (resultCode == 1)
```

much better to use the named constant --

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

`RESULT_OK` is -1, so that might be your issue.

Comment: how to know which button was pressed?

Comment: Oh, I see.  You are sending an int back instead of the standard result code.  The standard pattern is to send back RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCELLED and then result data in an `Intent` via this two parameter `setResult` method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: It looks like you are sending back an intent already.  Why not put which button is pressed in there?

Comment: So does it has another method to check which button was clicked ?

Comment: How can I pass the parameter k to new Intent and then return back the parameter k to onActivityResult to check which button was clicked?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in the extras of your return intent.  You are already extracting the String `a` from it with String b = data.getStringExtra("a"). In your activities, you have an intent.putExtra("a", [some string value].  You can also add intent.putExtra("button", [value of the button press]) and have it returned to the calling activity as well

Comment: Bro can you please update your answer?  Is this the correct way ? Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Project1.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0,k); ?

Answer (score 0):

Once I set all my request codes the same. Didn't work.
Seems your request codes *are* different,  I'm used to seeing them like this:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_THIS = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_THAT = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_THE_OTHER = 1003;

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (item == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new     Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Project1.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_THIS);
```

Check if changing the onActivityResult() like this might help.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_THIS) { // if button1 was clicked
        switch (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            case 0:
                   ...
        }
```